# How to subtract minutes from ISODate() in perl and mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, perl, aggregate, fastcgi

Actually, I want to subtract minutes from my execution time field (subtract 5 minutes)...
this is my mongodb collection :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c4f11fae2fb4adc98f323ad"),
    "datetime" : ISODate("2019-01-28T14:30:18.423Z"),
    "queuename" : "indotama_advice",
    "payload" : "xxxxxxx",
    "executiontime" : ISODate("2019-01-28T14:31:18.423Z")
}
```

this is my code :

```
my $collection = $db->get_collection('schedulequeue');
$person =  $collection->find_one({"queuename" => "indotama_advice"},{"executiontime"=>1,"_id"=>0});
my $new_data = $collection->aggregate([
        {'$subtract' => ["executiontime", 5 * 60 * 1000]}
]);
```

but I got error message `unrecognized pipeline stage name : $subtract`, can anyone tell me the correct way to use $subtract in perl ??

Comment: First of all `'$subtract'` isn't perl but a MongoDB pipeline operator.
Second, what is your intent? Could you explain better what are you trying to do? You want to update documents server side? Get documents and subtract some seconds?

Comment: yea, I want to get document and subtract some minutes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error clearly states, `$subtract` is not an aggregation pipeline stage. Use `$project` to transform query results:

```
    $collection->aggregate(
        [
            {
                '$project' => 
                    {
                        'alteredExecutionTime' => 
                            {
                                '$subtract' => ['$executiontime', 5 * 60 * 1000]
                            }
                    }
            }
        ]
    );
```

Comment: how about to update field execution time with this new data (after subtract by 5 minutes) ??